# Need help in automate option in excel to identify last row dynamically

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Last row in my automate script should be selected dynamically. Different excel contain different last rows and the automate option should identify last row and run the script to that row only and not beyond.

below is the code generated when i recorded the automate option. Below code contains instruction to run till row 3922. My other excels may contain data with in row 3922 or exceeding row 3922. can you change the code which helps me to find the last row dynamically and stop the script based on each different excel.

```javascript
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) 
{
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Insert at range C:C on selectedSheet, move existing cells right
    selectedSheet.getRange("C:C").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
    // Insert at range C:C on selectedSheet, move existing cells right
    selectedSheet.getRange("C:C").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
    // Set range C1:D2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("C1:D2").setFormulasLocal([["Age","Aging"],["=TODAY()-B2",null]]);
    // Set number format for range C2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("C2").setNumberFormatLocal("General");
    // Auto fill range
    selectedSheet.getRange("C2").autoFill("C2:C3922", ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillCopy);
    // Set range D2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("D2").setFormulaLocal("=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet1!A:B,2,1)");
    // Auto fill range
    selectedSheet.getRange("D2").autoFill("D2:D3922", ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillCopy);
    // Paste to range C:D on selectedSheet from range C:D on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("C:D").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("C:D"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.range?view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-range-getusedrange-member(1)

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you looking for is to optimize "auto fill range". You can get last row # before auto fill.

```js
    // get lastRow index
    let lastRow = (selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getLastRow().getRowIndex() + 1).toString();
    selectedSheet.getRange("D2").autoFill("D2:D" + lastRow, ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillCopy);
```

Comment: Thank you now its working but script is running to last but one row and not the last. If my last row is 6922 the script is working till 6921 and not 6922. I tried with different excels with different last rows and its stopping in last but one row.

Comment: You are right. The return value of `getRowIndex()` is zero-base. I have updated the code.